# Error when publishing a Shiny App [Application mode static not supported.]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, rsconnect

I am trying to upload a Shiny App on shinyapps.io using `rsconnect`.

However, it keeps throwing the following error:

> ℹ Uploading bundle...
> [100%] Uploaded 10853122 bytes...
> ✔ Uploaded bundle with id 7560635
> ── Deploying to server ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> Waiting for task: 1326449334
> error: Parsing manifest

> Begin Task Log

> End Task Log

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1326449335 failed: Application mode static not supported.

Based on my search, I believe that the problem might be in the fact that I am using Windows, but that's just a guess.

The code I am running is this:

```
rsconnect::deployApp(appFileManifest = "manifestation.txt", #Link to the file with file manifestation
                     appPrimaryDoc = "Production_Indices.xlsx",
                     appName="App_Name")
```

I have also tried to use `appFiles` instead, but the result would be the same.

If anybody has any ideas on what is going on here, I'd highly appreciate your help!